# Deformation retraction onto the boundary

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If I have a square and I remove an open disc from its interior, there exists a deformation retraction onto its boundary. Is this also the case, if I remove a closed disc from its interior? Does the same retraction work?

Comment: I think it does. I just want someone to ellaborate on this a little. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: yes, the restriction of a retraction when removing an open disk to what you obtain when removing the closed disk is still a retraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the retraction is given by mapping the point $x$ to the intersection of the boundary of the square and the line which goes through $x$ and the center of the removed disk (open or closed). As the center is in the interior of the square, this is well defined and, if we move $x$ along the line uniformly as $t$ runs from $0$ to $1$, then this is also a deformation retract.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up my doubt.